# merge date text in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

[image]i have sheet including a start date & sf id and I need to combine them in one column as a reference but when I try to do this I found an error as shown in the P.S, So can I solve this error[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
= Text.From([Date]) & Text.From([Person ID])
```

or perhaps

```
= Text.From([Date]) & " " & Text.From([Person ID])
```

If the field is not text, you can not combine it using a & unless you wrap it with Text.From()